# Reset $fid value of data table

Tags: field-calculator

Is there any way to reset fid value of data table? I'd to remove all data from table and I'd like to got '1' in fid column in first row for new entry.

Comment: While creating a new, empty shapefile would be easier, you simply can erase all features form an existing one and then newly created features should begin with ID 0.

Comment: ok, but is there any way to move all attributes and style to new shapefile?

Comment: Styles can be saved as `.qml`, while you can create attributes when creating the new file.